# LINQ Group By with multiple parameters

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a VB.NET application and want to do Group By on multiple columns.

**Class Structure:**

```
Public Class Person
   Public Property Name as String
   Public Property City as String
   Public Property Country as String
End Class

Dim oResult = PersonList _
                .GroupBy(Function(v) New With {v.City, v.Country}) _
               .Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1).ToList()
```

I have multiple person records which contains same city name & country name. But above query returns me zero items. if I am using only one column City or Country then it's working fine.

```
Dim oResult = PersonList _
                .GroupBy(Function(v) v.City) _
               .Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1).ToList()
```

Anyone point me where I am wrong with Group By LINQ query with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is that only `Key` properties in anonymous types are used in equality and hashing in VB. (*All* properties in C# anonymous types are effectively key properties.) So you just need to change your query to:

```
Dim oResult = PersonList _
                .GroupBy(Function(v) New With { Key v.City, Key v.Country}) _
                .Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1).ToList()
```

See the documentation for [anonymous types in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx) for more details.

Comment: What if we want to group by first character of city name ?  and include all which have only one single item in group ?

Comment: @rahularyansharma: I suggest you try that for yourself, using the answers here and other research, then ask a new question showing how far you've got and where you're stuck.

Answer (score 6):

```
Dim q1 = (From p In Repository.Table
                            Group p By p.CreatedDate.Year, p.CreatedDate.Month Into Group
                            Select New With {.Year = Year, .Month = Month, .Count = Group.Count()}).ToList
```

Or

```
Dim q2 = (From p In Repository.Table
                            Group p By key = New With {.Year = p.CreatedDate.Year, .Month = p.CreatedDate.Month} Into Group
                            Select New With {.Year = key.Year, .Month = key.Month, .Count = Group.Count()}).ToList
```