# Translating LINQ expression from C# into VB.NET throws exception in Group by

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have below Linq expresion in C# and it is working perfectly:

```
from c3 in equipment.Measures
where c3.IdEq == eq.IdEq && !(c3.magnitudeId == null || c3.magnitudeId.Trim() == string.Empty)
group c3 by c3.magnitudeId into cgroup
                  select new
                  {
                      MagnitudeID = cgroup.Key,
                      MaxDate = cgroup.Max(x => x.NextDate)
                  }
```

Now I am trying to convert it into VB.NET notation:

```
From c3 In equipment.Measures
Where c3.IdEq = eq.IdEq AndAlso Not (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c3.magnitudeId))
Group c3 By c3.magnitudeId Into grp = Group
          Select New With
          {
            .MagnitudeID = grp.Key,
            .MaxDate = grp.Max(Function(x) x.NextDate)
          }
```

... but I get an error message saying:

> 'key' is not a member of 'System.Collection.Generics.IEnumberable(Of
>   ...)'

Comment: Does this help ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660240/linq-group-by-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: VB.Net may need the "_" character for line continuation.  Not sure why you have "grp = Group" instead of just "grp".  I think you need the underscore and use same syntax as c#.

Comment: Incidentally, you could use `Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(c3.magnitudeId)` instead of `Not (c3.magnitudeId = Nothing OrElse c3.magnitudeId.Trim() = String.Empty)`.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the suggestion.I have corrected it in VB.NET code snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following (and also note that to be equivalent you need the 'Key' keyword in VB):

```
From c3 In equipment.Measures
    Where c3.IdEq = eq.IdEq AndAlso Not (c3.magnitudeId Is Nothing OrElse c3.magnitudeId.Trim() = String.Empty)
    Group c3 By c3.magnitudeId Into cgroup = Group
    Select New With {
        Key .MagnitudeID = magnitudeId,
        Key .MaxDate = cgroup.Max(Function(x) x.NextDate)
    }
```

It would be nice if the C# and VB teams had coordinated a bit since some of the differences in LINQ between C# and VB are very puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Group` instead of a named group

```vb
From c3 In equipment.Measures
Where c3.IdEq = eq.IdEq AndAlso Not (c3.magnitudeId = Nothing OrElse c3.magnitudeId.Trim() = String.Empty)
Group c3 By c3.magnitudeId Into Group
Select New With
{
    Group.First().magnitudeId,
    .MaxDate = Group.Max(Function(x) x.NextDate)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the other way (method syntax) of writing LINQ, it works (more closely to) the same way as in C#:

```
Dim q = (equipment.Measures).
    Where(Function(a) a.IdEq = eq.IdEq AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.MagnitudeID)).
    GroupBy(Function(b) b.magnitudeId).
    Select(Function(c) New With {Key .MagnitudeID = c.Key, Key .MaxDate = c.Max(Function(x) x.NextDate)})
```