# LINQ and lambda expression for duplicate (also reversed) routes

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda, duplicates

I have a VB .net application in which I want to check if a collection of routes have the same startLocation and destinationLocation, so basically a check for duplicate routes.

I have found a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660240/linq-group-by-with-multiple-parameters) for checking exactly the same route:

```
Dim duplicateLines = Routes.Values.GroupBy(Function(v) New With {Key startLocation, Key destinationLocation}) _
.Where(Function(grp) grp.Count > 1).ToHashSet
```

But I would also like to check for reversed routes i.e., the start of route 1 is the destination of route 2 and vice versa.

Is this possible with a similar, fast solution (e.g. with LINQ and lambda expressions)?

Thanks!

Comment: "fast solution (e.g. with LINQ and lambda expressions)" Fast because it needs just a few letters and is easy to read or fast because it's efficient? Because this area is something where LINQ is not your best friend in terms of performance.

Comment: @TimSchmelter "Fast" because if I use a ForEach loop (twice) it takes too long to check for duplicate routes. Btw the solution above is quite fast for large collections, but a faster solution is of course very welcome...

Comment: LINQ also has loops, you just don't see them. Maybe your approach is just inefficient because you don't use a set based approach(for example a `HashSet(Of T)` or a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` for the lookups). A loop has the advantage that you could check both use-cases at once, you probably don't need two for-each loops.

Comment: @TimSchmelter It actually is a dictionary of type (String, Route). How would you check for duplicate routes in only one loop?